# I accidentally sprayed bleach on some apples. Is this dangerous?

Tags: food-safety, food-science, vegetables, fruit, storage

When I was bleaching towels, I accidentally sprayed some on apples nearby. The next day, to be safe, I washed these apples for about 15 seconds. Are these apples safe to eat Could someone get sick?

Please answer for my peace of mind.

Answer (score 4):

At least in the US, as of 2017 (last reference I found), commercially packed apples are washed in a bleach solution, then thoroughly rinsed before being sold.   We, of course, have no way of knowing the concentration of your bleach spray, but I would think that if you washed these apples they are safe for consumption.

Comment: I just rinsed them under the tap. Is that good enough?

Comment: Hard to be definitive, again, not knowing the concentration, how much got on your apples, how you washed them...etc.   It is doubtful that any bleach got beyond the barrier of the skin.  I would be comfortable with them, but if anyone can point to a risk here, I would be happy to amend.

Comment: This is the safety sheet of the bleach. https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0580/1056/6835/files/C9955_Astonish_Mould_Mildew_Blaster_750ml_SDS_NEW_PACK_deca4c0e-01e3-4083-82f2-1bad12475ee6.pdf?v=1645634776

Comment: I would peel the apples before use. If you had washed them immediately, I don't think there would be a concern, but depending on the concentration and type of of the bleach etc, it may have damaged the skin cellulose. To be on the safe side, I would definitely peel them, and remove any damaged/discoloured flesh.

Comment: for sure if you wash it off right away and it doesn't smell like bleach, then it's fine. I worked at a pool where regular bleach was used for chlorinating the water; consuming a tiny amount (can't smell it) isn't harmful.